# I am trying to get max output in a 2d vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to get max output in a 2d array like
Input: accounts = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
Output: 6
Explanation:
1st customer has wealth = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
2nd customer has wealth = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6
Both customers are considered the richest with a wealth of 6 each, so return 6.

current input = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]];

current output = 12;

expected output = 6;

I can't understand why it's giving 12.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maximumWealth(vector<vector<int>>& accounts) 
    {
        int max , temp = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<accounts.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<accounts[i].size();j++)
            {
                temp = temp + accounts[i][j];
            }
            if(temp > max)
            {
                max = temp;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    };
```

update:

Now input : [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]

current output : 1849672928

expected output : 6

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger or manually using a scratch pad for variables.  Pay special attention to `temp`.  While you're at it, you may decide to give `temp` a more descriptive name.  What is it actually intended to be?  The sum of the values in a single sub-vector, right?  Is that what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-initialise an array's sum counter before inner loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<accounts.size();i++)
{
    temp = 0; // re-initialise before taking every array/account's sum here
    for(int j=0;j<accounts[i].size();j++)
    {
        temp = temp + accounts[i][j];
    }
    if(temp > max)
    {
        max = temp;
    }
}
```

Also, you should initialise your `max` variable as a very small value, e.g. `INT_MIN` or just 0 (if you don't have negative elements).

```
#include <climits>
int max = INT_MIN, temp = 0;
```

We set it to minimum so that for the first comparison, it's guaranteed that `max` will be set to one the elements inside your matrix. Later on, it's just comparison with other matrix elements.

Comment: Thanks, it's accepted but still, I didn't understand the concept.

Comment: You need to set the counter to 0 before you start taking the sum of every 1-d array. You need to reset the counter for every fresh account. Otherwise, you would add the sum from previous accounts/1-d arrays as well.

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted to close it. @BATMAN_X

Comment: Actually now there is another issue and I updated to question can you take a look at it.

Comment: Did you initialise your `max` variable as 0? @BATMAN_X

Answer (score 1):

```
var maximumWealth = function (accounts) {
    let a = accounts.map((e) => e.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
    return Math.max(...a)
};
```